# Envio de Formulario y Datos de Tabla a Controlador ASP .NET por AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, mvc, asp

Este es mi primera pregunta en esta plataforma. Soy nuevo con el framework ASP .NET y tengo un problema que les cuento:

Tengo una tabla que se va generado a medida que se agregan productos a ella para ser facturados. Tengo ademas un formulario con los datos de la factura.

Necesito enviarlos al controlador para ser procesados.

una clase que contiene los productos que estan en la tabla "ProdutosT", otra que recibe los datos de la factura DatosF. y Finalmente una clase que recive un objeto DatosF y una lista de ProductosT.

el problema es que no logro hacer que lleguen los dos elementos, el formulario de los datos y los productos al controlador

```
//clases
    public class ProductoT
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public float cantidad { get; set; }
        public float precio { get; set; }
    }
```

public class DatosF
{
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public string TipoPago { get; set; }
    public string PrecioSelect { get; set; }
    public string DiasCredito { get; set; }
    public string Vendedor { get; set; }
    public string PrecioEditable { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
}
public class FaturaPuntoV
{
    public DatosF datosF { get; set; }
    public List productosF { get; set; }
}

//Javascript
$(".pagar").click(function () {
            var TableData = new Array();

`$('#tabla_productoF tr').each(function (row, tr) {
        TableData[row] = {
            "codigo": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "cantidad": $(tr).find('td .cantidadProducto').val()
            , "precio": $(tr).find('td .precioItemN').val()
        }
    });

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name]) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
    })(jQuery);
    y = new Array();
    var i = $("#FormularioFactura").serializeFormJSON();


    y.push({ DatosF: i });
    y.push({ ProductosT: TableData });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FacturacionPuntoV/Create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json,utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(y),
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (result) {
        },
        success: function (result) {`

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. ¿tienes errores con este código?, ¿cómo estás probando consumir este servicio?. [edit] tu pregunta suministrando mas información

Comment: **if (!o[this.name].push)** ¿Hacer esto es válido?